# Skip the slot that is already booked and reschedule slots

Tags: algorithm, logic

Each slot is of 30 mins duration staring from a given time with a rest time of 2mins. For example my StartTime is 16:58. so the slots are below

```
16:58 - 17:28
17:30 - 18:00
18:02 - 18:32
18:34 - 19:04
19:06 - 19:36
19:38 - 20:08
```

and so on

I want to skip those tiime slot  which are clashing with a given time slot. say, 17:45 - 18 : 06

so now the slots should be

```
16:58 - 17:28
18:08 - 18:38
18:40 - 19:10
19:02 - 19:32
19:34 - 20:04
```

I need the logic to work out this programatically. It will be great if somebody can help me.

Comment: What are the tags like java,javascript and php doing in this question?

Comment: any programmer can suggest. bacically I'm php (larvel framework). Do i need to remove those language tags?

Comment: @Shalom then why the other tags?

Comment: Yes please, avoid tagging all languages that you can